# Why does Lazet's hair color suddenly change?

Tags: 07-ghost

In episode 4, when Teito meets Lazet for the first time she looks [like a brunette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHbV7.jpg), but a few moment afterwards (something like 10 seconds), her hair color [changes to pink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU4ND.jpg) without any noticeable reason (and apparently no one seems to be bothered by it at all).

Although I didn't see the whole series, I'd like to know if this phenomenon has been explained later in the series, or has it just remained unexplained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

> She is not a human, but a Noel Mermaid, who has an ability to change their face's appearance. Her original face is the one with pink hair and eyes.

So, when Teito met Lazet,

> She mimicked Teito's face: brunette hair and green eyes.

---

References:

- 07-GHOST Wikia: [Razette](http://07ghost.wikia.com/wiki/Razette)